# content is undefined,error is Error:ENOENT,open 'C:\Windows\system32\hello.txt'

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, cmd

I just started learning node.
Here is my problem, I got sample.js file

```
var fs=require("fs");
console.log("starting");
fs.readFile("hello.txt" , function(error,data){
    console.log("content is asdas " + data);
});
console.log("executed");
```

and hello.txt with content, they both are on my desktop

```
hello
```

When I run this as administrator in powershell or cmd

```
C:\Windows\system32\ node C:\Users\X\Desktop\sample.js
```

I get

**starting**

**executing**

*content is asdas undefined*

when I log error

```
var fs=require("fs");
console.log("starting");
fs.readFile("hello.txt" , function(error,data){
    console.log("content is asdas " + error);
});
console.log("executed");
```

I get

**starting**

**executing**

*content is asdas Error:ENOENT,open 'C:\Windows\system32\hello.txt'*

So I guess that error is that node is looking in system32, not in desktop...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js [resolves relative paths](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to) from the [current working directory](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) rather than from the current script/module.

> If after using all `from` paths still no absolute path is found, the current working directory is used as well.

In this case, that would be:

```
console.log(process.cwd());
// outputs: C:\Windows\system32\
```

To specify a path relative to the script, you have to resolve/join/etc. the path yourself from [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname):

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + "/hello.txt", /* ... */);
```

```
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "hello.txt"), /* ... */);
```

```
fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "hello.txt"), /* ... */);
```

Comment: now i get content is asdas null

var fs=require("fs");
console.log("starting");
fs.readFile(__dirname +"/hello.txt" , function(error,data){
 
 console.log("content is asdas " + error);


});
console.log("executed");

Comment: @LauroSkr Since you're logging `error`, `null` is actually a good thing (no errors reading the file). Try swapping back to logging `data`. And, if you get something like `[object Buffer]`, try passing it as a separate argument rather than concatenating it yourself. `console.log()` should then give it a friendly format.